# Localhost is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: php, server, command, apache2

This page isn’t working

`localhost is currently unable to handle this request.`

HTTP ERROR 500

I know this is some sort of server error. I spend almost whole day with this error. I checked the logs and still i can't trace the error. I checked the similar errors in here but all that solutions don't helped me.
please help. Thanks.

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/myPro/web/wp-content/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/taxonomy-terms-order.php:134\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/myPro/web/wp-settings.php(273): include_once()\n#1 /var/www/myPro/web/wp-config.php(88): require_once('/var/www/myP...')\n#2 /var/www/myPro/web/wp-load.php(39): require_once('/var/www/myP...')\n#3 /var/www/myPro/web/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/var/www/myP...')\n#4 /var/www/myPro/index.php(17): require('/var/www/myP...')\n#5 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/myPro/web/wp-content/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/taxonomy-terms-order.php on line 134`

this is the error that i get in the error log.

Comment: This is a PHP error, not an Apache error.

Comment: so how can i solve it ?

Comment: Find someone who knows PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem caused because wordpress is not ready to support php7. I used `php7.2` and a downgraded version of`wordpress`. So that php is not supporting the wordpress.

Two solutions,
One is to update the `wordpress` and other is to downgrade the `php`.
I don't want to update `wordpress` so i downgraded the `php7.2` version to `php5.6`. Now it works fine.